# How can I link an invite code to a user? DISCORD.JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I have an invite create command, but whenever it creates an invite it does it under the bots ID. I'm wondering if there is a way I can add the invite code to a different user ID so when they use an invites command, it will show the amount of invites that specific code has sent.  Bump

````
module.exports = {
    commands: 'invites',
    requiredRoles: ['Affiliate'],
    callback: (message) => {
    if (message.channel.id === '824652970410770443'){
      var user = message.author
      message.guild.fetchInvites()
      .then

      (invites =>
          {
              const userInvites = invites.array().filter(o => o.inviter.id === user.id);
              var userInviteCount = 0;
              for(var i=0; i < userInvites.length; i++)
              {
                  var invite = userInvites[i];
                  userInviteCount += invite['uses'];
              }
              const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                .setColor('#1AA2ED')
                .setTitle(message.author.username + "'s Invites")
                .setDescription(`Invites: ${userInviteCount}`)
                   message.reply(embed).then((msg) => {
                     message.delete()
                   })
          }
      )
    }
    if (message.channel.id !== '824652970410770443'){
        message.reply(`You can't do that here`)
    }
  }
    
}; ```
````

Answer (score 0):

You can not change the Invite Creator that Discord knows, however you could locally store which user created which invite link.

This would however have to be done when in the command that creates an invite.

You have multiple options on how to store this data, but the simplest one would just be writing the data to an Object that associates the User ID to the Invite ID, then stringifying and saving that Object to a file whenever your bot exits and loading and parsing that file whenever your bot starts.

Then, whenever you need to know which user created an invite link, look it up in that Object.

Comment: I'm still new to JS so it's still a bit confusing, do you have any code examples of this? thanks for the help